# Cannot resolve JSP specific tags while receiving from ModelAndView object

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets, model-view-controller

From the controller, I can send an attribute back to a JSP page through a ModelAndView object and receive it through an EL tag in JSP, i.e ${message}.

HTML tags are resolved and displayed in the JSP page without a sweat, but JSP specific scriptlets and tags are not getting resolved.

My issue is this: From the controller, all responses must be directed to two pages, a success page, and a failure page. The content displayed on each page is determined by the attribute being sent through a ModelAndView object, and this attribute is to contain a message describing something, and a JSP directive or action to *include* another JSP page.

In the controller servlet:

```
public ModelAndView request(){

    String message = "This is the text returned by the servlet! <br><hr> " 
            + "<jsp:include page='WEB-INF/views/anotherpage.jsp'></jsp:include> ";

    return new ModelAndView("blank","message",message);
}
```

In the JSP page 'blank.jsp', is an EL tag: ${message}

The HTML tags `<br>` and `<hr>` are resolved correctly, and the text is being displayed. But nothing is being displayed for `<jsp:include />` nor is it including the mentioned file.

How do i invoke JSP directives and actions from the servlet page ?

Comment: EL resolution is compiled into the generated JSP servlet. All tags that appear in the JSP are converted to their corresponding Java code. But the value of `message` is resolved at runtime. It will not be evaluated as a JSP element/tag.

Comment: @sotirios: Thanks, understood! Is there another way to get around this ? The include action has to be called at run time, can it be precompiled at a different place and then be sent ?

Comment: @AkashMurthy: pass a flag indicating which page to include, or the name of the page to include, and use that in your JSP to include the right page.